# Django Decorator View Not Callable

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have written two very simple decorators for my django app :

```
def login_required_json(f):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #this check the session if userid key exist, if not it will redirect to login page
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            result=dict()
            result["success"]=False
            result["message"]="The user is not authenticated"
            return HttpResponse(content=simplejson.dumps(result),mimetype="application/json")
        else:
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

def catch_404_json(f):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            result=dict()
            result["success"]=False
            result["message"]="The some of the resources throw 404"
            return HttpResponse(content=simplejson.dumps(result),mimetype="application/json")
```

But when I apply them to my views I get "ViewDoesNotExist" error in the template, saying it could not import the view because it is not callable. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show how you're applying the decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def login_required_json(f):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #this check the session if userid key exist, if not it will redirect to login page
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            result=dict()
            result["success"]=False
            result["message"]="The user is not authenticated"
            return HttpResponse(content=simplejson.dumps(result),mimetype="application/json")
        else:
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner   # <--- Here
```

Your decorator is returning None, instead of the actual view.
So return the inner function as I've demonstrated above.